# IncomingMessage abort event

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stream

I have this basic express (4.13.3) server in Node (4.2.3).

```
//blah blah initialization code

app.put('/', function(req, res) {

  req.on('close', function() {
    console.log('closed');
  });

  req.on('end', function() {
    console.log('ended');
  });

  req.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });

  res.send(200);
});
```

Then I simulate file upload using cURL like this:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/ -X PUT -T file.zip
```

It starts uploading (although nothing happens with it) and when it ends, event `end` fires.

The problem starts when I abort the upload with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
No event fires at all. Nothing happens.

`req` object inherits from `IncomingMessage`, thus inherits from `Readable`, `Stream` and `EventEmitter`.

Is there any event at all to catch such an abort? Is there any way to know if the client aborts file upload?

## First edit:

User @AwalGarg proposed `req.socket.on('close', function(had_error) {})` but I'm wondering if there is any solution to this which is not using sockets?

Comment: What about the [abort event](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/http.html#http_event_abort)?

Comment: The `req` object has a `socket` property. `req.socket.on('close', ...)` is the event you are looking for. Under normal completion, the `'end'` event is emitter otherwise.

Comment: He says the program is already listening on `end, close, error` and nothing fires.

Comment: @marekful `abort` event applies to `http.ClientRequest`, `req` has no connection here.

Comment: @marekful he is listening on the `req` object, not `req.socket` object.

Comment: @AwalGarg It's not the solution, because it fires even when upload is successfully finished.

Comment: @AreWojciechowski If you look at the documentation closely, the callback recieves an argument `had_error` which can be used to verify whether the upload was successful or not. https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_close_1

Comment: @AwalGarg I see that Question is: would be help to listen on socket events, too?

Comment: If there's an event for the case when the client aborts a request and you want to detect exactly that, what is preventing from going to that direction?

Comment: There is no such event in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code sets up some event listeners, then sends the response back to the client right away, thereby completing the HTTP request prematurely.

Moving `res.send()` inside the event handlers, keeps the connection open until one of those events takes place.

```
app.put('/', function(req, res) {

  req.on('close', function() {
    console.log('closed');
    res.send(200);
  });

  req.on('end', function() {
    console.log('ended');
    res.send(200);
  });

  req.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.send(200);
  });

});
```